# Counting durations from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, time, momentjs

I need to investigate how much long machine has been running and standby. I have entries in database like so:

```
| machine | running | start               |
|---------|---------|---------------------|
| 1       | 0       | 2018-03-13 00:00:00 |
| 1       | 1       | 2018-03-13 00:30:00 |
| 1       | 0       | 2018-03-13 02:00:00 |
```

Time is now `2018-03-13 04:00:00`. When using example above, the results should be `01:30:00` (running) and `02:30:00` (standby).

What is the best way to do this kind of calculations? Is my database entries good enough?

I'm using tools like Laravel in backend, and f.ex. Vue and Moment.js in frontend. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this does the trick:

```
<?php

$rs = [
    [
        'machine' => 1,
        'running' => 0,
        'start' => '2018-03-13 00:00:00'
    ],
    [
        'machine' => 1,
        'running' => 1,
        'start' => '2018-03-13 00:30:00'
    ],
    [
        'machine' => 1,
        'running' => 0,
        'start' => '2018-03-13 02:00:00'
    ],
    [
        'machine' => 1,
        'running' => 1,
        'start' => '2018-03-13 03:00:00'
    ],
];

$lastState = -1;
$startDateTime = $endDateTime = null;
$totalStates = count($rs);

foreach ($rs as $r)
{
    $machine = $r['machine'];
    $running = $r['running'];
    $start = $r['start'];

    if (-1 === $lastState) {
        $startDateTime = new \DateTime($start);
        $lastState = $running;
    }
    else {
        $endDateTime = new \DateTime($start);
        $dateTimeInterval = $endDateTime->diff($startDateTime);

        echo "State: ". $lastState ." / Total time: " . $dateTimeInterval->format("%H:%I:%S") . "\n";

        $startDateTime = new \DateTime($start);
        $lastState = $running;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
State: 0 / Total time: 00:30:00
State: 1 / Total time: 01:30:00
State: 0 / Total time: 01:00:00
```